# How do I view and edit Visual Basic Power Pack shapes in a Windows Form app with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer, shapes, powerpacks

I've got a windows forms app created in an older version of Visual Studio.  When I open it in VS 2017, none of the Power Pack shapes are show in the design view.  I've got the Power Pack dll in references.  I tried to add them to the toolbox (General, Choose Items, .Net Framework Components), but the shapes like Rectangle Shape are missing.  How can I either get them to display in the design view or add new ones through the toolbox?

Here is the reference to Power Pack:
[image]

Here's the choose toolbox item where you can see RectangleShape is missing:
[image]

Here's the code where the rectangle is defined:

```
private Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape StandardFiltersToUseRectangleShape;

this.StandardFiltersToUseRectangleShape = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape();
this.StandardFiltersToUseRectangleShape.BorderWidth = 3;
this.StandardFiltersToUseRectangleShape.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(626, 82);
this.StandardFiltersToUseRectangleShape.Name = "StandardFiltersToUseRectangleShape";
this.StandardFiltersToUseRectangleShape.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(600, 15);

this.shapeContainer1.Shapes.AddRange(new Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Shape[] {
this.StandardFiltersToUseRectangleShape,
this.FiltersToBuildRectangleShape});
```

Comment: You are looking into a wrong assembly. You need to look into `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.dll`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking into a wrong assembly. You need to look into `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks` assembly.

[Visual Basic Power Packs Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/windows-forms/power-packs-controls) are not included in Visual Studio by default. First you should [download](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=321343) and install them. Then to add them to the toolbox:

Right click on *ToolBox* → *Choose Items ...* → *Filter* for *powerpacks* → Check controls → click *OK*.

[image]